# Ubuntu 20.04 earbud bluetooth mic not detected

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, microphone

I've a earbuds with microphone (Veatool) and Ubuntu 20.04 recognize them but just for output, not for input.
I tried lot of things as Setting -> Sound -> Configuration (output) -> Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) but input device continues showing just Built-in Audio.
Also adding each of following options on `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-hda-intel position fix=1
#options snd-hda-intel model=stereo-dmic
#options snd-hda-intel model=aspire-headset-mic
#options snd-hda-intel model=alc294-lenovo-mic
#options snd-hda-intel model=lenovo-y530
#options snd-hda-intel model=headphone-mic-pin
#options snd-hda-intel model=dmic-thinkpad
```

My Laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad E14.

Last thing was removing

`rm -rf ~/.config/pulse/`

Comment: Have you tried them in another OS or computer? Do they work with Ubuntu maybe contact the seller and ask.

Comment: Yes, it worked on Android phone, macbook and laptop Windows